# Admob add at bottom

Tags: android

I'm working on an app and I've have Admob and i want to add at bottom of my layout. I'm using Appcompat toolbar. Using android:layout_marginTop is not a good idea. Below i've posted the Main.xml where i'm using admob integration in the app and the Toolbar which is made by using AppCompat Toolbar is also mentioned below as Toolbar.xml

Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#212121"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>


 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dip"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_switch_on"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#000"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="150dp"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"

    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: What is issue ??  if possible show in image.

Comment: @Vickyexpert how to do it

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only this : `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Remove this :  `android:layout_below="@+id/btnSwitch"`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" 
>

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dip"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_switch_on"
    android:background="@null"
     android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSwitch"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/adUnitId_banner" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Remove this `android:layout_below="@+id/btnSwitch"` no need if you are using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in `AdView`.

**Do only.**

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner"/>
```